# Count no of records as per the date from table and format the date using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need to etch no of records as per the date filed and after fetching the data I need to format the date using PHP and MySQL. I am explaining my table below.

db_audit:

```
id        auditname         date    
 1          xxxx            2017-12-01 12:26:49  
 2          sss             2017-12-01 12:20:00   
 3         fff              2017-12-01 12:00:00 
 4        hhh              2017-12-02 12:27:49   
 5        ttt              2017-12-02 11:26:49     
 6       yyy               2017-12-03 10:26:49
```

Here I need to fetch no of records as per the date only. Here for `2017-12-01` there are 3 records present. I need to push all data into an array like this key format `{'no_records'=>3,'date'=>2017-12-01}`. Here also I need to formatted the database date field value from `2017-12-03 10:26:49 to 2017-12-03` and it should be in string format. Here I need the query to retrieve these type of value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query like below to get date in the required format

```
select count(*), DATE_FORMAT(dateTimeColumnName,'%Y-%m-%d') as date from tableName group by DATE_FORMAT(dateTimeColumnName,'%Y-%m-%d');
```

This will give you result number of rows per day

Example

```
+-------+------------+
| count | date       |
+-------+------------+
|     3 | 2017-12-03 |
|     1 | 2017-12-04 |
|     1 | 2017-12-05 |
+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

First part of the code to select the data according to the queries

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db="";//database name
//connection
$conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$db);

//query to select data matching the  data    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db_audit where date='2017-12-01' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

 $date=substr($row['date'],0,10);
    $values=array("no of records=> $count","date=>$date");
?>
```

The end part formats the data to the desired output

Comment: Here there is no user input.

Comment: u want the date to be user input??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(`id`) as no_records, DATE(`date`) as date FROM tableName GROUP BY DATE(`date`);
```

Comment: Add some descriptions